# Are those properties sufficient for defining a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Consider the following properties:

1. $a(x+y) = ax + ay$
2. $x + y = y + x$
3. $ax = xa$
4. $x + 0 = x$
5. $x \cdot 1 = x$
6. for every $x\ne 0$ there's a $y$ such that $xy=1$.

Are those enough for defining a field?

Comment: As a minimum they would need some quantifiers. But I doubt you can derive the associativity from these.

Comment: Another example of a structure that satisfies these axioms, but is not a field, is the set $\{0, 1\}$, with the $+$ operator being the "maximum" operator and the $\cdot$ operator being the "minimum" operator.

Comment: Without $1 \not = 0$ you could have the zero ring with a single element

Comment: You also need $0 \neq 1$. The set with one item: {0} satisfies these axioms, too (with 0=1).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These axioms do not require the existence of the opposite (for addition). The set of the not negative rational  numbers with the usual operations satisfies these axioms and is not a field.

Answer (score 5):

No. You still need additive inverses and the two associative properties. As a quick counterexample, consider the set of all nonnegative <strike>integers</strike> reals $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x\ge0\}$. They satisfy all six properties. But it's not a field because there are no additive inverses.

Comment: The nonnegative integers do not have inverses as required here.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Oops, sorry... I still need to wake up fully. :-) Of course, they don't. But reals or rationals would do. Thanks!